# Not getting how rewriting URLs exactly works

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am not able to grab the concept behind rewriting URLs regardless of so many articles on the web about it.

Suppose absolute path of the webpage I want to see is `www.abc.com/games.php?game=1`. I want the link `www.abc.com/games/game/1` to redirect to the above page.

Wouldn't this rule work for it?

```
RewriteRule games/game/([^/\.]+)/?$ games.php?game=$1 [L]
```

My `.htaccess file`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule games/game/(\d+)/?$ games.php?game=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Wouldn't this rule work?"

```
RewriteRule games/game/([^/\.]+)/?$ games.php?game=$1 [L]
```

Yes, it would work. But your regular expression can be simplified and improved:

1. `(...)` - characters in brackets will be captured - correct, that's what we need.
2. `[^/\.]` - will match any characters, that are not in character class; i.e. any symbol, that is not a slash `/` and not a dot . - this is not fully correct. We need to match any number of digits: \d+. But your regexp will match non-digital symbols as well.
3. `/?$` - possible slash at the end of string

So, we can rewrite your regexp like this:

```
^games/game/(\d+)/?$
```

I added a cap symbol at the beginning, so we can be sure, that the URL starts from "games".

This site may be helpful:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. The page opened but here comes another problem. Nothing is passed in `GET` variable

Comment: Is the redirect correct? Maybe, $1 wasn't used. Let me check on my machine.

Comment: @NavneetSaini hm, I created a simple php script: <?php var_dump($_REQUEST); ?> - and game variable is passed. The same for $_GET: <?php var_dump($_GET); ?> Check it, please.

Comment: okay, it isn't working for me.I am trying it, though. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you please explain me what does `$1` actually do?

Comment: @NavneetSaini It is a backreference to the matched text in brackets: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: I noticed that if I used this regex, I am not able to open any page of my website. 500 internal error always occurs whether or not I am trying to access the link `www.abc.com/games/game/1`

Comment: @NavneetSaini Can you post your entire htaccess? I think, something else is wrong there.

Comment: Posted in the question. But there is nothing much in it.

Comment: @NavneetSaini Remove QSA for now. And put a cap symbol before games: ^games. I updated my answer. But cap won't help.

Comment: If I remove QSA, the link works but now, nothing is passed through `GET` method

Comment: @NavneetSaini Did you var_dump($_GET);? I can't believe, that nothing is passed.

Comment: No. I didn't.. Is it necessary to use `var_dump`. Can't I directly use `$_GET['page'];` ?

Comment: You made a mistake: you are using $_GET['page'], when the variable is called `game`. You need to use $_GET['game'] or change the rewrite rule: `RewriteRule games/game/([^/\.]+)/?$ games.php?page=$1 [L]`

Comment: No, It's fine in my script. I made a mistake here instead. Is it necessary to use `var_dump`?

Comment: The thing is when I use this rule and include `QSA`, even the homepage doesn't open. Nothing opens. 500 internal error everywhere. And when I don't use `QSA`, nothing is passed through `GET`.

Comment: @NavneetSaini " Is it necessary to use var_dump?" - no, I just wanted to see, what variables are passed. Ok, now, when you changed the rule, the variable is passed.

Comment: @NavneetSaini Please, don't use QSA flag, if you don't understand, how it works: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: @NavneetSaini "Doesn't work still :(" - maybe you are having some other variables. Put: `var_dump($_REQUEST);exit;` in the beginning of the script and show me, what it prints.

Comment: I will do that in a moment. Please could you answer this. If I write the rule as `RewriteRule /brush/page/ index.php [L]` and then if I type `www.abc.com/brush/page/` in the browser, it should redirect me to the home page, right?

Comment: @NavneetSaini No, remove the first slash: `RewriteRule brush/page/ index.php [L]`

Comment: Ok, fine. I think I got the problem. Nothing wrong with this thing. I wish I could give you more points for this answer. I am making an AJAX request through an external `.js` file. Now, till now, I was using relative paths. Do I need to change them to absolute now?

Comment: @NavneetSaini I think, it must work correctly with relative. But you can make an experiment, changing them to absolute. Sorry, need to do my work now. I think, this question is solved - rewrite rule must work. If you have any more errors, create a new question, providing maximum information to the people: .htaccess, result of var_dump($_REQUEST); in your php, javascript, sending ajax request.

Comment: That's absolutely fine, man. Really, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with query strings and rewrite rules, you need the "QueryString Append" option.

> qsappend|QSA’ (query string append) This flag forces the rewrite
>   engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the
>   existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to
>   add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

So, you should use this:

`RewriteRule games/game/(\d+)/?$ games.php?game=$1 [L, QSA]`

Now you can acccess `$_GET['game']` from your processing page.

Comment: But when I do this, internal server error occurs. '500 internal sever error' to be precise.

Comment: Well, can you try to use your previous regular expression (by @user4035), just add QSA parameter inside square brackets at the end of your rewrite rule. You still get internal server error?

Comment: Can you please explain me what does $1 actually do?